# Partial Values for Knuth's Up-Arrows

Tags: power-towers

$3 \uparrow 4 $ is $3^4$, and $3\uparrow \uparrow 3$ is $3^{3^{3^3}}$, etc.  For those of you unfamiliar, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation) is a wiki page on the notation.  Clearly, up-arrow expressions, as they are usually defined, only have meaning when the number of arrows is in the naturals.  Is there an extension, similar to $\Gamma (x)$ and the factorial function, that extends this to all reals, or even complex?

Comment: Maybe first look for a definition of $a\uparrow\uparrow b$ for non-integer $b$ before we start looking at a non-integer number of arrows :P

Comment: Paulsen and Cowgill already took care of that for us. http://myweb.astate.edu/wpaulsen/tetration2.pdf

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Notation) says that there are many different notation styles that can be used to express tetration. In the same page, you can see some explanations about [the extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Extensions).